# Proxy username/password with Twisted

Tags: python, proxy, twisted

I'm trying to use Twisted's [ProxyAgent](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.1.0/api/twisted.web.client.ProxyAgent.html) class to connect to a proxy server and make HTTP requests, however the server requires a username and password. Is it possible to specify these credentials to the server using ProxyAgent?

```
endpoint = TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, host, port)
agent = ProxyAgent(endpoint)

# Maybe need to pass auth credentials in the header here?
body = agent.request("GET", path)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out the problem, the Proxy-Authorization field has to be set in the headers:

```
endpoint = TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, host, port)
agent = ProxyAgent(endpoint)

headers = {}
auth = base64.b64encode("%s:%s" % (username, password))
headers["Proxy-Authorization"] = ["Basic " + auth.strip()]

body = agent.request("GET", path, Headers(headers))
```